# How do I shuffle a list with constraints in Python where some elements cannot appear after another element

Tags: python

I've read a few posts on conditional shuffling/randomizing but can't find anything which quite answers my question.

I have two lists containing strings:

```
fruit = ['apple', 'pear', 'banana', 'orange'...]
labels = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'D'...]
```

Each list may contain duplicates.

What I would like to do is shuffle a list combining both fruit and labels where the position of any one label in the new list may occur anywhere before, but not after the corresponding fruit so that I get something like this:

```
fruit_and_labels = ['D', 'orange', 'B', 'B', 'banana', 'A', 'pear', 'apple'...]
```

I have tried a number of methods but can't figure out a solution in which this condition is always true for all fruits in the resulting list.

I'm new to python so apologies if this is badly worded or thought through question - all feedback is welcomed with open arms!
Thanks

Comment: what is the 'corresponding string' ? do you mean the label? if so, 'orange' appears after it's label...

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the use cases of such a shuffle? :)

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Isn't it obvious? Distributing fruit and labels.

Comment: what is the 'corresponding string' ? which type of output needed?? can you give a sample output?

Comment: @yurib and S_A Sorry - that wasn't clear at all. By corresponding I mean strings with the same list index in the original two lists. For example in the first two lists I gave 'apple' and 'A', 'pear' and 'B', 'banana' and 'B' etc. Is that clearer?

Comment: @harry_jones you wrote no *fruit* should appear after the corresponding string, but that is clearly not the case in your example output, i think you meant no label should appear after the corresponding fruit.

Comment: @yurib you are correct! thanks for pointing that out I will correct the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

judging by the example output, i assume you meant no label should appear after it's fruit. if that's the case:

```
import random

fruit = ['apple', 'pear', 'banana', 'orange']
labels = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'D']

# shuffle fruits
result = list(fruit)
random.shuffle(result)

# insert labels at random positions 
# between the beginning of the list and the corresponding fruit
for l,f in zip(labels,fruit):
    result.insert(random.randint(0,result.index(f)),l)

print result
```

output:

```
['D', 'B', 'banana', 'orange', 'B', 'A', 'apple', 'pear']
```

Comment: Perfect! and so simple now that I see it. I tried a similar thing with zip by shuffling the whole list but didn't think to insert the labels afterwards. Thanks a lot for your help.